# Changing order of Angular formGroup controls

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am building an Angular application that dynamically renders a form through a `formgroup object` as follows:

```
    <div *ngFor="let controlName of updateValuesForm.controls | keys">
      <input [formControlName]=controlName type="text" class="edit-template-input" />
    </div>
```

In certain situations however, I want to swap the order two of these controls in my formgroup object. Is that possible with an Angular `formgroup object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, Object in Javascript doesn't have an order and it dosn't make sense for them to have.

You can use a FormArray, which internally has an array to hold your controls and change the order that way.

Or if you really wany to do it with object, you probably have to store your controls inside an array and change the order that way.

Answer (score 0):

A `FormGroup` is internally an object and so therefore has no inherent order.

If you put your controls in a `FormArray` you will then be able to change the order of the controls using their index.

You can use methods like `insert` `removeAt` and `push` to manipulate the order of the controls within the `FormArray` by their array index accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I used an unclever but effective method,**put the bottom line at the top of the name and the order you want**

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   A : ....,
   B : ...
})
```

change to

```
this.formBuilder.group({
   _1_A : ....,
   _2_B : ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls of `FormGroup` can be copied in the desired order.

**Original order:**

```
this.form.controls = {
  A: ...,
  Z: ...,
  B: ...
}
```

**Desired order:**

```
this.form.controls = {
  A: this.form.controls.A,
  B: this.form.controls.B,
  Z: this.form.controls.Z
}
```

Tested in chrome, firefox and safari.

Answer (score 0):

6 years later, the order of the `formGroup.controls` is relevant, because 'high-performance-deserialization' requires the metadata fields like `$type` to be on the top of the serialized json.

But `value` returns the order of `formGroup.controls`.
So, to order the controls and bring all metadata fields (starting with `$`) on top, you can do the following:

```js
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function sortFormGroupControls(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    const controls = { ...formGroup.controls };
    const sortedKeys = Object.keys(controls).sort((a, b) => {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    });

    Object.keys(controls).forEach(key => {
        formGroup.removeControl(key);
    });

    sortedKeys.forEach(key => {
        formGroup.addControl(key, controls[key]);
    });
}
```